# Is there a way to modify a power bi field parameters via rest api?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded

There is something called  [Field parameter](https://endjin.com/blog/2022/06/how-to-dynamically-switch-between-measures-in-power-bi-visuals-with-field-parameters#:%7E:text=Field%20Parameters%20allow%20you%20to,interested%20in%20within%20a%20slicer.)s in Power BI Desktop. If a am to embed it on Web Applications, is there a way now to directly change it's value?

Answer (score 2):

You can create multiple field parameters in Power BI Desktop and With the Edit API and In edit mode you can switch between the parameters. But can't change the parameter formula itself in the Embedded